# How to use material-ui-pickers's date picker with ReactJS's State Hook and pass date to the parent component?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I am trying to use  [material-ui-pickers's date picker](https://material-ui-pickers.dev/api/datepicker), where example demos are written using [State Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html). I would like to get the date's value as a callback to the parent component.
This is the child component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import { DatePicker, InlineDatePicker } from "material-ui-pickers";

function YearMonthPicker(props) {
const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState("2013-01-01");

  return (
        <div className="picker">
          <DatePicker
            openTo="year"
            views={["year", "month"]}
            label="Year and Month"
            helperText="With min and max"
            minDate={new Date("2011-01-01")}
            maxDate={new Date("2018-12-01")}
            value={selectedDate}
            onChange={handleDateChange}
          />
        </div>
  );
}

export default YearMonthPicker;
```

On "onChange", the function modifies its "selectedDate" state.

In my parent component, I defined the function:

```
handleChangeTo = e => {
    this.setState({ dateTo: e.target.value });
};
```

And, in the render method, I am trying to call it as such:

```
<YearMonthPicker handleChangeTo={this.handleChangeTo} />
```

**As I understand it, If I change the function of "onChange" to props.handleChangeTo, then the child component's state will not be updated upon change. What's the right way to pass the date to the parent component?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using `handleDataChange` directly as the handler for `onChange` you can create a new function that calls `handleDataChange` and `handleChangeTo` from the props. `handleChangeTo` would then get the value directly, and not an event.

**Example**

```
function YearMonthPicker({ handleChangeTo }) {
  const [selectedDate, handleDateChange] = useState("2013-01-01");

  return (
    <div className="picker">
      <DatePicker
        openTo="year"
        views={["year", "month"]}
        label="Year and Month"
        helperText="With min and max"
        minDate={new Date("2011-01-01")}
        maxDate={new Date("2018-12-01")}
        value={selectedDate}
        onChange={val => {
          handleDateChange(val);
          handleChangeTo(val);
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Alternatively you could keep this state in the parent component and pass it down as props to `YearMonthPicker` and not have any component state in the child at all.

Comment: Did you mean `props.handleChangeTo(val);` instead of `handleChangeTo(val);`?

Also, regarding "handleChangeTo would then get the value directly, and not an event", I'm not sure I follow, how do I get the date from the parent component?